# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Desde el controlador ejecuto la siguiente consulta:

```
    $pruebas = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t2.name AS 'Type',
    t4.company AS 'Company',
    t4.name AS 'clientName',
    t4.lastname AS 'clientLastName',
    t4.email AS 'Contact',
    t3.name AS 'Status',
    t1.created_at,
    t1.`when` FROM quotation t1
    JOIN quotation_type t2 ON t1.id_quotation_type = t2.id
    jOIN quotation_status_type t3 ON t1.id_quotation_status_type = t3.id
    JOIN client t4 ON t1.id_client = t4.id") );

    return view('home')->with("pruebas", $pruebas);
```

Quiero cargar los datos obtenidos en una tabla pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string  (View: /Users/Hernan/Desktop/BRAVALL/project/resources/views/home.blade.php)

En el html esta por defecto la tabla y no entiendo cual es el problema, ayuda please:

```
                    @if(count($pruebas) > 0)
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Tipo</th>
                            <th>Empresa</th>
                            <th>Cliente</th>
                            <th>Contacto</th>
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            <th>Fechaa</th>
                            <th>Fechab</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @if (count($pruebas)) @foreach ($pruebas as $prueba)
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="/quotedetail?data=<?echo urlencode("$prueba");?>">#{{ $prueba->id }}</a></td>
                            <!-- <td><a href="/provider?data={{$prueba}}">#{{ $prueba->id }}</a></td> -->
                            <td>{{ $prueba->Type }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $prueba->Company }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $prueba->Client }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $prueba->Contact }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $prueba->Status }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $prueba->created_at }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $prueba->when }}</td>
                        </tr>

                        @endforeach @else
                        <h1>No hay registros</h1>
                        @endif
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                @else
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    No se encontrarón registros
                </div>
                @endif
```

El arreglo que retorna es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

El problema se debe a la línea:

```
 <!-- <td><a href="/provider?data={{$prueba}}">#{{ $prueba->id }}</a></td> -->
```

Ya que aunque este comentada la linea de donde imprimes con blade la variable $prueba igual el motor de plantillas de laravel blade va interpretarla como una variable php y al ser un arreglo y no un string te produce el error.

Comment: 1. Hay otra línea antes que no está comentada.  2. Esto no agrega nada comparado con mi respuesta.

Comment: Entiendo pero aún así cuando hay una linea arroja el mismo error, al hacer click en el id mi intención es mandar el arreglo a otra vista.

Answer (score 0):

En los enlaces estás pasando el objeto y no el valor que necesitas para completar la url, probablemente sea el id o un slug:

```
<td><a href="/quotedetail?data={{urlencode("$prueba->id")}}>">#{{ $prueba->id }}</a></td>
<!-- <td><a href="/provider?data={{$prueba->id}}">#{{ $prueba->id }}</a></td> -->
```

Comment: pase la variable y funciona! pero necesito mandar el objeto completo del id seleccionado.

Comment: Para eso utiliza Route Model Binding: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: Si esta respuesta te sirvió, puedes marcarla como aceptada.